# Inheritance problems, why can not print the right result?

Tags: java, inheritance

the requirements are:

Create a file Hop.java with a public class named Hop.
Create two other classes: Skip a subclass of Hop and Jump a subclass of Skip.
Create a no-argument constructor in each of the three classes that prints the name of the class on a line by itself (e.g., use System.out.println(“Hop”) to print the “Hop” class name.
Create a main method (where?) and create a new instance of Jump.
Compile and run. You should see the output Hop, Skip, and Jump printed to standard out. Can you explain it?

and the code I write so far is :

```
public class Hop {
    private String name;
    public Hop(String name) {   
        this.name = name;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Jump j = new Jump("Hop", "Skip", "Jump");
        System.out.println(j);

    }
}
class Skip extends Hop {
    private String name1;
    public Skip(String name, String name1) {
        super(name);
        this.name1 = name1; 
    }

}
class Jump extends Skip {
    private String name2;
    public Jump(String name, String name1, String name2) {
        super(name, name1);

        this.name2 = name2;
    }

}
```

Comment: Look at your constructors - they each have parameters, and they don't print anything. There's nothing that says you should print out the newly created instance. Basically, you need to read the instructions more carefully.

Comment: *"Create a no-argument constructor in each of the three classes that prints the name of the class on a line by itself (e.g., use System.out.println(“Hop”) to print the “Hop” class name)"* would suggest you're not following the instructions provided

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the question is asking you to do:
(The intention of the question is to demonstrate that all super class constructors are implicitly called (recursively) when an instance of a subclass is created.)

```
public class Hop {
    public Hop() {   
        System.out.println("Hop");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Jump j = new Jump();       

    }
}
class Skip extends Hop {
    public Skip() {
        System.out.println("Skip ");
    }

}
class Jump extends Skip {
    public Jump() {
        System.out.println("Jump ");
    }
}
```

Read the question carefully. Follow the instructions. Try to think what the question is meant to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I know where where is wrong in my code!